# How is it possible to build an ios app and getting .ipa without certificate in codenameone

Tags: ios, certificate, codenameone, iphone-developer-program

i creating a app with Codenameone. i want to build it in ios and test it on ios before buying a apple developering account. how is it possible ?
can i use some other certificate for this kind of building just for testing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Codename One will build your app with our certificate if you don't fill in the details. It isn't guaranteed to work and it will only install on a jailbroken device.

This is a restriction imposed by Apple which doesn't allow you to run an application on your own device without a certificate.

Answer (score 1):

You can use some other certificates. Tell some of your friend to provide you the certificate and private key exported from their keychain. You also need a provisional profile from same friend with wild card. It will allow you to not to register you bundle ID on the portal. Tell the friend to add your iOS device UDID into the provisional profile as well. Now you should able to do it.

If you really want to go ahead with iOS, better to buy.